# Can an element be removed from the DOM if a descendant node's link had already been visited?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

CSS allows to modify the style of an a:visited link but, can an element be removed from the DOM if a descendant node's link had already been visited?

Comment: Yes the `:visited` pseudoclass is only CSS and isn't even part of the DOM.

Comment: My question is, given a sample element structure like div > p > a, can I programmatically remove all div elements from the DOM that contain an already visited link? If that's possible at all, how exactly could that be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

Researching on this topic, I've found [this article](https://www.kirupa.com/html5/finding_elements_dom_using_querySelector.htm), which states:

> Not all pseudo-class selectors are allowed. A selector made up of
>   :visited or :link is ignored and no elements are found.

The use of the :visited pseudo-class is limited because of privacy concerns, as a malicious site could otherwise potentially know which of some given URLs you've visited.